# Transfer Directives to Child DOM Elements

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've created a custom directive that is essentially a textbox with some augmented markup.

```
module.directive("inputField", ["$log", function($log) {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        labelText: "@"
      },
      templateUrl: "input-field.template.html"
    }
  }]);
```

Template File:

```
<div class="fancy-field">
  {{ labelText }}:
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

I want my directive to support adding standard HTML5 input attributes and Angular directives and apply them to the child input.  I accomplish this by transferring selected attributes from the parent `<div>` element to the inner `<input>` in the directive's compile function.

```
  compile: function(element, attributes) {

    var inputElement = $(element.children("input")[0]);
    if(attributes.innerDirective) {

      // Transfer the inner-directive element specified on the parent
      // to the child input
      inputElement.attr("inner-directive", attributes.innerDirective);

      // Remove the attribute specified on the outer element
      // in a futile attempt to keep the inner-directive
      // from applying to the outer div
      $(element).removeAttr("inner-directive");
      delete attributes.innerDirective;
      delete attributes.$attr.innerDirective;

    }

    return {};

  }
```

This succeeds in applying supported attributes and directives to the `<input>`, and also removes the attributes from the outer element in the DOM. However, it does not prevent directives from being applied to both the inner and outer elements.  I want to be able to control this, so that supported input directives (e.g. ng-pattern) can be transferred to my input without having any side effects on the outer div.  I also want to avoid the unnecessary overhead of processing a directive I don't want to use.

I've created a Plunkr to demo the behavior.  It logs to the console to prove that the inner-directive applies to both inner and outer elements.

https://plnkr.co/edit/3qLt6mzcVkEcYbEHg81s

Is this possible to accomplish in the way I am describing?  How should be I creating a custom directive that can properly apply directives to it's children?

Comment: One thought is don't use the `ng-` prefix on outer attributes so they don't get compiled as angular directives

Comment: Maybe, but I don't like the idea of having to have special ways to use directives on this control.  Also, my example is a custom directive that doesn't even use `ng-`, so it would potentially make the alternative name even more weird (if I use up the good name on the actual directive :))

Comment: In that case it's really not clear what you are asking. You stated you didn't want angular invoking directives. As example sometimes I'll use `model="somVar"` and use that to set `ng-model`

Comment: I'm trying to create a custom control that functions exactly like a normal `input`.  Any directives you can use on a textbox you should be able to use here, in the exact same way.

Comment: Understand that part, not really clear what your specific issues are

Comment: The issue is that I can't keep the directive from being evaluated on the parent element, even if I remove it at compile time (without using custom attributes that will map to real directives inside my directive like you suggest). This leads to a directive being applied twice. I think that I may have discovered the solution though, and will post when I can answer my own question (or when someone swoops in with the answer to get points )

Comment: So I gave you a fix that would resolve that but you didn't like it. There is no other magic way to use a core directive attribute and not have it get compiled. By the time you are removing attributes it's too late

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by setting a high `priority` for my directive and also setting `terminal` to `true`.

```
  module.directive("inputField", ["$log", function($log) {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      replace: true,
      priority: 1000,
      terminal: true
      // ... Rest of definintion ...
    }
  }]);
```

The higher priority helps ensure that my `input-field` directive is processed first and `terminal` tells angular to stop compilation of the remaining directives which are lower priority than `input-field`.  This allows me to defer the actual processing of these directives until they have been transferred to the appropriate child element.

This updated Plunker shows the fix in action:

https://plnkr.co/edit/NoUwGKn11oc86hbtqTik